# PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 78 bytes)

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I am having an issue with Wordpress. I built the website on Wamp and everything is working fine. Now i just uploaded it and I am having a Fatal Error.

I figured that I don't get the error when I rename my plugin folder.

I have also increased the memory in default-constants.php to the following and still nothing.

```
    // Define memory limits.
if ( ! defined( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT' ) ) {
    if ( false === wp_is_ini_value_changeable( 'memory_limit' ) ) {
        define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', $current_limit );
    } elseif ( is_multisite() ) {
        define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M' );
    } else {
        define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M' );
    }
}
```

I still have the error 500. It must be coming from a plug-in but I just can't tell how to fix it.

Comment: Well neither can we unless we can see the code for the plugin. And if you show us the COMPLETE Error message rather than a summary, we will at least know where the error is coming from. Please remember, knowbody here **is clairvoyant**

Comment: Oh and that error does at least tell us that you have exceeded the 128M memory limit, so at least we know your `memory_limit` change worked

Comment: In order to enable the error logging define debug log in `wp-config.php`
`define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );`

Comment: That's all there is to the error message. The rest is just location of the file. PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 93 bytes) in /home/davidjiv/public_html/wp-includes/pomo/mo.php on line 272

Comment: You need to change the memory limit for PHP not Wordpress, probably in the php.ini file

Comment: The error is coming from he WooCommerce plugin. But why is it working fine in localhost

Comment: Did you check what the php.ini sets the memory limit to on your dev machine

Comment: Usually unless you explictly know that you are doing some memory demanding work _out of memory_ error indicates bug with code. Problem with debugging such errors is that it often doesn't tell you what part exactly is causing such memory consumption. I would start debugging by first disabling plugins until this error disappears to pinpoint plugin at fault.

Comment: Also worth noting: making changes to WordPress core files (`default-constants.php`, in this case) is a really bad idea. Define `WP_MEMORY_LIMIT` in `wp-config.php` instead.

Comment: post_max_size = 256M in php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

So I couldn't figure out how to fix the issue. I had to restart the process using anothor method. 
I intalled wordpress on the server and used the All-In-One Wp Migration plugin and it did the job perfectly.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score -1):

This could actually be database related. Im guessing either the 'Collation' or the ... which should be UTF-8 Unicode. When UTF-8 Sweden for example is used, you only get 196 characters, which is too short for most encryptions. It should be 255 characters long.

Check this out in your database.

Comment: Not in a million years.